# Read the XML using Linq and check if the elements exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to read the XML using linq and check if the element exists and gets it value.

For example if the element is like `<Name />` then Im getting NullException. How to check if its value is null or not and also if exists in the XML in single statement.

Comment: Use `(string)element("Name")` - the explicit cast to `string` will safely handle nulls.

Comment: How to check if the Name exists in the XML? This wont work if Name doesnt exist in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [explicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:-

```
string result = (string)x.Element("Name");
```

**Update:**

If element itself is not present then you can use [C# Null Colaescing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator like this:-

```
string result = (string)x.Element("Name") ?? "Default Value";
```

Comment: Thank You! But What if <Name> Tag doesnt exist? Name Tag may or may not be present in the XML..How to handle this?